# Casting Struct Array to Interface Array Generates Error

Tags: c#, class, oop, struct, interface

I need to cast an array of structs into an array of interfaces. VS lights up red. Is there any way to get around this limitation?

```
interface ISomeInterface
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Class : ISomeInterface
{
    public string name { get; set; } = "Class";
}

public struct Struct : ISomeInterface
{
    public Struct() { }

    public string name { get; set; } = "Struct";
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var classArr = new Class[] { new Class(), new Class() };
        var structArr = new Struct[] { new Struct(), new Struct() };

        ISomeInterface[] interfaceArr;
        interfaceArr = classArr;  //normal work
        interfaceArr = structArr; //error
        interfaceArr = (ISomeInterface)structArr; //error
        interfaceArr = (ISomeInterface[])structArr; //error
    }
}
```

Even through the cast does not work.

Comment: You need to create a new array, if you're going to insist on working with arrays. The structs would need to be boxed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because value types need to be boxed when represented as a interface. I.e. `interfaceArr` is an array of references to `ISomeInterface`. While `structArr` does not contain references, but the actual values themselves. Since values and references are different things you get an error.

I would generally avoid casting arrays altogether, since this can also cause some other possible problems. If you need to convert some type of collection to another I would suggest using LINQ:

```
interfaceArr = structArr.Cast<ISomeInterface>().ToArray();
```

This will create a new array of the specified type.

Comment: To explain further: C# has array covariance for reference types, which is why `(ISomeInterface[])classArr` works